# Make input="text" auto width (Cross-browser solution)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make a input="text" box auto adjust its width in a cross-broswer solution? In the example below the textbox adjust its width so its reaching the "text" text. Is there any crossbroswer-solution for this (IE6 and newer)?

jsfiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/P4Qd8/1/**

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">Label</div> 
    <div id="right">Text</div>
    <div id="middle">
        <input id="info" input type="text">
    </div>   
</div>
```

And CSS

```
#wrapper{height: 100px; width: 350px; border: 1px solid blue;}

#left{float:left;}
#middle{float:left;}
#right{float:right;}

#info{width: 100%;}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: So you tested this in IE and it didnt work? (My Chrome seems to work as desired)

Comment: I don't understand, does this ***not*** work? if so, what browser?

Comment: This dont work in IE6 and IE7 becuse of overflow:hidden. The middle div is placing itself on a new row and is being 100% width of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question has `JQuery` tag let me show you an example with it. You can use JQuery to set the width in IE, haven't tested in IE6(I don't care about and you should do the same) but it's JS and should work. You can load this only in IE and manipulate the element in CSS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = $('#middle').width();
    var padding = $('#middle input').css('padding').replace('px','');//the padding defined in css
    var border = $('#middle input').css('border-width').replace('px','');//the border width
    $('#middle input').css('width', width-padding-border*2);
});
```

Over this, I really don't understand why you say that `width: 100%` it's not working in IE because it should.

**Edit:** JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P4Qd8/4/

Comment: Width 100% works in IE, the problem is that width 100% is making the textbox 100% of its parent element. And the div the textbox is placed in is floating without any width so the result is that its 100% of that parent element.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use auto?

```
#wrapper{height: 1em; width: 350px; border: 1px solid blue;}
#left{float:left;}
#middle{float:left;}
#right{float:right;}

#info{width: auto;}
```

Comment: No then the div just adjust itself to the textbox size.